# Send email via Android app

Tags: android, email

I've been trying to write a program which can send emails and I've gone to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application).

However, neither of its answers work. I tried the the code given in the accepted answer and Android SDK is giving me this alert: `no application may perform this action`. The other code, given by yuku, gives `Unsopported action: This action is not currently supported` alert.

Can someone help me with this? Any step by step tutorials?
By the way, I would prefer a solution which doesn't require a prompt asking which email server is the user using, but that's optional and extra for now.

I also tried:
[Sending e-Mail in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137662/sending-e-mail-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, the first, best and easiest ways is using the email intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@domain.ext");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Another way is to code a server-side script that sends email, in php, python are any other server-side language and then connect to it from your app to send emails.

Comment: Thank u at last i'm not getting errors!but it's sending a MMS mail not an email! therefore i cant find it in the reciptants inbox

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/) is a step by step tutorial on how to send email in Android.

Comment: hmmm frist it told me that my phone(emulator thing) doesnt have any mail service so i installed one then it wasnt working...but that seems good